# Get <p> tag content in ejs variable

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I want to store `<p>` tag content in ejs variable.

```
<div id="testDiv">
    <p id="num">5</p>

<% 
    var val = 0;
    val = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;
    console.log(val);    // val = 5
%>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, well... at least not directly. `ejs` is rendered on server not on client so it doesn't have access to `document` which is provided by browser.

If you want to use JavaScript on client then you should probably change `ejs` for simple `script` element.

```
<div id="testDiv">
  <p id="num">5</p>

  <script> 
    var val = 0;
    val = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;
    console.log(val);    // val = 5
  </script>

</div>
```

Although I would advise agains such an approach, and would move the JavaScript code to external `js` file.

But if you really need to get that value into `ejs` for whatever reason, then you can extract it with JavaScript like this, send it to server and re-render the view with that value.

Comment: Can we store `<script>` variable value in `ejs` variable? @Matus Dubrava

Comment: @shaibazBadai Well, yes and no. Code enclosed by `<% %>` is server-side JavaScript. Code in `<script>` element is client-side JavaScript. Those are two different environments which can't communicate with each other directly, only through requests. So again, if you want to get some value from client-side variable into `<% %>`, then you need to send that value to server in some request and re-render the view with that value passed to that view.